# Getting strange exception in OpenXml SDK 2.5

Tags: validation, ms-office, excel-2010, openxml-sdk

I have a simple file *.xlsx created in Office 2010 with 3 spreadsheets. Only first is used and have easy formula like Sum and Multiplication in cells. It also contains 17 columns and 4k rows filled. Data types of the cells are: Numeric, Short Date, Long Date and Text. When I'm trying to read that file using OpenXml SDK 2.5 and validate it to make sure this file is correct I'm receving this strange exception:

> ErrorType: Schema.
>
> Error Description: The attribute 'verticalDpi' has invalid value '0'. The MinInclusive constraint failed. The value must be greater than or equal to 1.

This is method how I'm reading and validating:

VB.NET:

```
Using spreadsheet As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(m_FileName, False)
    Dim validator As New OpenXmlValidator
    Dim errorsValidation As IEnumerable(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Validation.ValidationErrorInfo) = validator.Validate(spreadsheet)
    If Not errorsValidation.Any() Then
        'Do something here if it's correct
    Else
        Console.WriteLine(errorsValidation.First().Description)
    End If
End Using
```

C#:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(m_FileName, false)) {
    OpenXmlValidator validator = new OpenXmlValidator();
    IEnumerable<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Validation.ValidationErrorInfo> errorsValidation = validator.Validate(spreadsheet);
    if (!errorsValidation.Any()) {
        //Do something here if it's correct
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine(errorsValidation.First().Description);
    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and what is wrong. Can't find any issues to how to fix the file. Any idea, suggestions?

Comment: I had the same error highlighted above.  Simply copying the whole spreadsheet and pasting (as values) to a new spreadsheet resolved the problem.  I do not know the root cause of the error, however.